# Why can't I cast an array of Objects to an array of a generic subclass of a generic class?

Tags: java

This code is valid. It compiles and run with a "unchecked or unsafe operations" warning.

```java
class Foo<T> {
  T[] items = (T[]) new Object[10];

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();
  }
}
```

While these 2 are giving me runtime error

```java
class Foo<T> {
  class FooItem { T item; }

  FooItem[] items = (FooItem[]) new Object[10];

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();
  }
}
```

```java
class Foo<T> {
  static class FooItem<E> { E item; }

  FooItem<T>[] items = (FooItem<T>[]) new Object[10];

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();
  }
}
```

The error I encountered is as follow:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [LFoo$FooItem; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [LFoo$FooItem; is in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader

Why is this?

Comment: `"these 2 don't compile"` is misleading. You're getting a runtime exception, not a compiler error.

Comment: You're right they actually compile! I've edited the question to state it as a runtime error.

Comment: Array variance in both Java and C# is just broken.  https://web.archive.org/web/20100629084706/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All versions of your `Foo` class have the same problem. The `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object[] to X` warning that you're ignoring just shows its consequences at different stages during execution.

Here's a way to break your first version:

```
class Foo<T> {
    T[] items = (T[]) new Object[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();

        Integer i = foo.items[1] * 2;
    }
}
```

It crashes with... the same problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    at stackoverflow.Foo.main(Main.java:17)
```

Why? Because `(T[]) new Object[10];` is not enforced at compile time, i.e., the compiler does not know how to validate the relationship between `T[]` and `Object[]`

Just as you can't cast `new Object()` to `Integer`, you can't cast `new Object[10]` to `Integer[]`. It's just that this class cast exception only shows up when the actual casting is run. For the first snippet, it does not run on the declaration statement, `T[] items = (T[]) new Object[10];` (hence the warning), but when `items` is used as whatever the type argument is for `T`.

Your other versions show the problem sooner simply because they're casting to a concrete type, such as `(FooItem[]) new Object[10]`, causing the declaration statement itself to crash.

Why does the compiler allow this cast? Because the type relationship is valid, given that such code as

```
Object[] items = new Integer[10];
Integer[] i = (Integer[])items;
Integer val = i[0];
```

is valid and supported.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot cast an `Object[]` into `T[]` is that this could lead to issues with the following code:

```
Object[] objects = new Object[10];         // This is fine
objects[0] = "Hello World";                // Is fine since String is subtype of Object
T[] ts = (T[]) objects;                    // One could argue that this is fine
T firstT = ts[0];                          // Now we have the issue that String needs to be casted to T
```

Because of this casting `Object[]` into `T[]` is not allowed. The same is the case for generics like lists.

Comment: `T[] ts = (T[]) new Object[n];` is actually allowed with a warning with Java. I think that cast  is only acceptable for generic types.

Comment: Yes, it is allowed, but it gives a warning, exactly for the reason above. But I agree, the formulation "cannot" might be a little misleading. Generics are a little different there since this is a construct that only exists during compile time.